# Why does php mysqli_prepare select query return null?

Tags: php

I'm using php to get data from database, but i have a problem.

First of all, It is php file which gets data from database.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(mydatabase_address, myid, password);

$userLocation = $_POST["userLocation"];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM neighborTable WHERE postLocation = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userLocation);
mysqli_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ID, $postWriter, $postContent, $postDate, $postPic, $postLike, $postComments, $postLocation, $profilePic, $postGatherDate, $postGatherLocation, $postGatherTime);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    $row_array['ID'] = $ID;
    $row_array['postWriter'] = $postWriter;
    $row_array['postContent'] = $postContent;
    $row_array['postDate'] = $postDate;
    $row_array['postPic'] = $postPic;
    $row_array['postLike'] = $postLike;
    $row_array['postComments'] = $postComments;
    $row_array['postLocation'] = $postLocation;
    $row_array['profilePic'] = $profilePic;
    $row_array['postGatherDate'] = $postGatherDate;
    $row_array['postGatherLocation'] = $postGatherLocation;
    $row_array['postGatherTime'] = $postGatherTime;

    array_push($response, $row_array);
}

echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

However, it returns like below. It has correct number of data, but its values are all null. How can i solve this problem?

```
{"response":[{"ID":null,"postWriter":null,"postContent":null,"postDate":null,"postPic":null,"postLike":null,"postComments":null,"postLocation":null,"profilePic":null,"postGatherDate":null,"postGatherLocation":null,"postGatherTime":null},{"ID":null,"postWriter":null,"postContent":null,"postDate":null,"postPic":null,"postLike":null,"postComments":null,"postLocation":null,"profilePic":null,"postGatherDate":null,"postGatherLocation":null,"postGatherTime":null},{"ID":null,"postWriter":null,"postContent":null,"postDate":null,"postPic":null,"postLike":null,"postComments":null,"postLocation":null,"profilePic":null,"postGatherDate":null,"postGatherLocation":null,"postGatherTime":null}]}
```

Comment: `mysqli_execute`? Maybe `mysqli_stmt_execute`?

Comment: @u_mulder 'mysqli_execute' works in otehr php files. I'll try to use mysqli_stmt_execute thanks

Comment: Although I used `mysqli_stmt_execute`, it doesn't work. I think it's not a case of grammar

Comment: Make sure you bind all fields returned as a result.

Comment: Try specifying the columns in the query

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks, I have omitted one column. It's truly my mistake. Thanks for replying